# How do I enable secure user data access using Firebase without requiring user to login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Say I'm building some basic not-so-secure Android app, and I want to use firebase as a DB, but I really don't want the user to login. What would be my best choice of authentication?

1. If I allow "Annonymous" login - will this mean a big security hole, or would it just mean that programmatically I am allowed to change data anywhere in the db?
2. Does firebase support automatic creation/logging of user using my own custom user/id mechanism (without any user intervention)? Docs aren't very clear about that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous log-in just provide authentication, that means you can associate a Unique ID to each of your user.
This de facto create a user ID and a Auth Token that is persisted in the phone between runs of your app. Token is refreshed when you call `signInAnonymously()`.
Check [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) for hits on how to handle anonymous logins.

Talking about security, anonymous login is not a bad practice. Obviously if you want to keep your DB safe you have to write custom access rules:
e.g. you probably want "anon_user322" to read your page content, but definitely not to modify or delete it.
Achieving this is not so hard, you have just to go to your [FirebaseConsole](https://console.firebase.google.com) and write your own rules for the Database.
You can find [on this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-authentication) a good starting guide. I suggest to watch [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUBnlbjZFAI) from Google I/O 2016, it is a bit long but you will be able to understand the basic of authentication and security in Firebase Database just with the first 25-30 minutes.

Comment: Wait... Does that mean every user has access to any other user's data?

Comment: @rubmz If you don't specify any access rules, then yes. Firebase DB is a cloud database, every client reads and writes to the same database. If you want to have data which only one person or a group of people can read you have to set the appropriate read and write access rules. Doing this is fairly simply, just refer to the basic Firebase documentation.

Comment: Try the talk I linked above, it is really easy to understand and will probably answer to most of your questions.

Comment: Seems the best solution is just to do a user/password login. There's no need for a login dialog - which was my assumption from the start.

Comment: I don't think user/password login will solve the problem even if you manually provide user/psw to your users. Without _custom access rules_ all **authenticated** user will be able to read **all** Database including other users data.

Comment: Okay, good point. So you say I need to add a few server rules? And no advantages for the named users in that aspect?

Comment: "So you say I need to add a few server rules?" Yes.  
"And no advantages for the named users in that aspect?" Depends on what your business is like. You can specify some data to be completely **public-visible**, some other just to **anonymous user**, other for **email-psw-authenticated people** and so on.  
Of course you can also decide that some data are available only to a certain user, or users group (for example _AdaLovelace_'s profile data will be writable only by her and no other)

Comment: Great. Okay, I guess that sums it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was using annoymous sign in at first but it has somedown sides like you cannot export and import the exact same user on another device. Therefore i started using password authentication. You can just generate an pseudo email via uuid@yourappdomain.com and also generate the password and keep it within the appdata.
For security purpose you wont get around setting up rules for writing and reading data but it is working quite simple and easy enough to test with both methods annonymous and passoword auth.